# Use do.call to get information out of a list of RC/S4 objects

Tags: r, list, r-s4, reference-class, do.call

I have a defined reference class and a list:

```
RCclass<-setRefClass("RCclass",field=list(info="character"))
A<-RCclass$new(info="a")
B<-RCclass$new(info="b")
testList<-list(A,B)

do.call(function(x){paste0(x$info)},testList)
```

The do.call function doesn't look quite right, and it doesn't give me the expected string "ab". However I am not sure how to achieve this. Please share your opinions; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution around this:

```
Reduce("paste0",(lapply(testList,FUN=function(x)x$info)))
```